# WordPress negates DB_COLLATE in wp-config

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, installation, collation

I'm having trouble installing WordPress on my localhost development area. Everything is working fine, but when I want to move my site to an online environment problems are showing up with the DB collation.

I read about this and it seems that WordPress created tables on my localhost using the utf8mb4_unicode_ci charset/collation. Although my online environment has an higher version of mysql running, it won't import the tables when moving.

I decided to force WordPress to use an older db collation on my localhost. So I changed wp-config to this, before running the setup:

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');
```

I saved it and ran the setup. A quick check in the database resulted in tables still in utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation!

How to force WordPress to use the utf8_general_ci collation?

Comment: did you tried to first create the DB manually (`phpMyAdmin` for example ) and then run the install on the same empty database ?

Comment: Yes, pre-created the db manually with the utf8_general_ci collation but somehow it doesn't make a difference to the endresult.

For now I use WP Migrate DB to make a sql dump and automatically convert it back to sql 5.0 compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Before installing, comment the line in wp-config-sample.php

```
// Define ('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
// Define ('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Create a database manually with utf8_general_ci and then install wordpress.

The tables are installed with default collate the database.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to contact the hosting company to upgrade their sql, I'm using a DB migrate tool right now to move websites.

Comment: This is awesome. I was having major issues with Wordpress not respecting the databases settings.